# Android: java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.android.phone (uid=1001) does not match provided uid 10246

Tags: android, sms, android-securityexception

**Scenario:** We are sending SMS to particular number if user grantees the SMS permission.

**Devices:** Only Samsung devices with Android 11.

**Code:**

```
SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(subscriptionId)
.sendTextMessage(destinationAddress, null, getString(R.string.xyz)
.format(token), sendSMSPendingIntent, null)
```

**Exception:**

````
java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.android.phone (uid=1001) does not match provided uid 10246

android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull Parcel.java:2385
android.os.Parcel.createException Parcel.java:2369
android.os.Parcel.readException Parcel.java:2352
android.os.Parcel.readException Parcel.java:2294
com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendTextForSubscriber ISms.java:2102
android.telephony.SmsManager$1.onSuccess SmsManager.java:618
android.telephony.SmsManager.sendResolverResult SmsManager.java:1627
android.telephony.SmsManager.resolveSubscriptionForOperation SmsManager.java:1588
android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessageInternal SmsManager.java:613
android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage SmsManager.java:451```
````

Comment: Can you update the question to include the specific SMS permission the user granted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the root cause.

When SIM card is inactive then device may throw the Security exception.

**Solution:** Just replace with working SIM card.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You have to check the airplane mode status and mobile network status before trying to send sms.

**Skip send sms call and show error message if airplane mode is enable or signal strength is zero.**

Check airplane mode:

```
public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
       return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
}
```

check mobile network

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
public static boolean isNoSignalStrength(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Service.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    return telephonyManager.getSignalStrength().getLevel() == 0;
}
```

I got the solution from this link https://askandroidquestions.com/2021/08/04/samsung-android-11-java-lang-securityexception-package-com-android-phone-uid1001-does-not-match-provided-uid-10571/?unapproved=6705&moderation-hash=ad920e86b8ab19ada9b29f39694490d5#comment-6705

Comment: Is this a common issue with Samsung devices? The URL you provided is not currently working.

Comment: Yes, Samsung updated os code for android 11 or higher. Other OEM devices don't throw any exception on send sms failure due to network strength. I am not sure why url is not working but you can try above code to fix the problem.